# (XF) Can only call API value from one class

Tags: c#, json, api, xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I got these classes (JsonData are just a few classes with getters and setters for the Json value from the API):

GetSetJsonData:

```
 class GetSetJsonData
{
    HttpClient client;
    #region SuccesLogin
    JsonData.SuccesLogin.RootObject succesLogin;
    JsonData.SuccesLogin.Session session;
    JsonData.SuccesLogin.Data2 data2;
    JsonData.SuccesLogin test;
    #endregion
    #region CompanyData
    JsonData.CompanyData.RootObject companyDataMatchPage;
    JsonData.CompanyData.RootObject companyDataMyNetwork;
    JsonData.CompanyData.RootObject companyDataAllCompanies;
    #endregion

    //uristrings for connecting
    string uriLoginString = "url";
    string uriGetCompanies = "url";

    public string sessionString { get; set; }

    public bool MakeConnection(string email, string password)
    {
        succesLogin = new JsonData.SuccesLogin.RootObject();
        session = new JsonData.SuccesLogin.Session();
        data2 = new JsonData.SuccesLogin.Data2();
        var userdata = new JsonData.UserLogin.Login()
        {
            userdata = new JsonData.UserLogin.Userdata()
            {
                user_email = email,
                user_password = password
            }
        };
        var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userdata), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        client = new HttpClient();
        var response = client.PostAsync(uriLoginString, content).Result;
        var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        succesLogin = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonData.SuccesLogin.RootObject>(responseString);
        if (succesLogin.success == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            session = succesLogin.success.data.session;
            sessionString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session);
            data2 = succesLogin.success.data.data;
            return true;
        }

        //implement failure system
    }

    //testing only
    public void Test()
    {
        sessionString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(session);

    }
}
```

LoginPage:

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    //DummyData DD = new DummyData();
    MasterDetailPageSetup masterDetail = new MasterDetailPageSetup();
    GetSetJsonData getSetJsonData = new GetSetJsonData();
    Test test = new Test();

    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Implement: return true of false when login is successful or not
        if (Email.Text == null && Password.Text == null)
        {
            if (getSetJsonData.MakeConnection(Email.Text, Password.Text) == true)
            {
                //getSetJsonData.Test();
                test.Help();
                //var test = getSetJsonData.sessionString;
                //masterDetail.SetupMasterDetailPage();   
            }
```

When I call MakeConnection from the LoginPage I get data in the GetSetJsonData class, no problem at all. Now when I call the Test() or the sessionString from the LoginPage it still works, BUT when I try to call this from any other class it for some reason only shows null values, even though I did save them. I just can't seem to make it work and I kinda gave up hope, anything to do this right?

Comment: it's impossible to say without seeing more code, but I suspect that in your other page you are creating a NEW instance of the GetSetJsonData class, but expecting it to have the same data as other instances of the same class.  That's not how OOD works.  If you want to share a single instance of a class, consider a Singleton or static class.

Comment: @Jason would that be a singleton or static GetSetJsonData class?

Comment: @Jason and yes, I am creating a new class in there, it was actually a thought that came by but didn't know how to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the GetSetJsonData class as a new instance in LoginPage and also other Page. In this case, the GetSetJsonData class and also sessionString inside the class will only available inside LoginPage.

If you want to make the sessionString available for all places, you can have few options:

1. Make GetSetJsonData class as static class `public static class GetSetJsonData`
2. Make GetSetJsonData class as a Singleton class. Refer to [HERE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx) for more details

   ```
   public class Singleton
   {
       private static Singleton instance;

       private Singleton() {}

       public static Singleton Instance
       {
           get 
           {
               if (instance == null)
               {
                   instance = new Singleton();
               }
               return instance;
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Put GetSetJsonData instance as a public property in other static class or singleton class. For example: in App class.

   ```
   public partial class App : Application
   {
       public GetSetJsonData GetSetJsonDataInstance { get; private set; }

       public App()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           GetSetJsonDataInstance = new GetSetJsonData();
       }
       ...
   }

   // Then you can access to the instance using:
   ((App)Application.Current).GetSetJsonDataInstance
   ```